# sql errors in a zencart

Tags: mysql, sql, zen-cart

I'm getting a couple of sql errors but I'm not too sure what to do with them, can someone tell me how to fix this?

[03-Mar-2012 13:36:42] PHP Fatal error:  1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), 'Y', 'N') as flag FROM manufacturers WHERE manufacturers_id IN (0,) ORDER BY ' at line 1 :: SELECT manufacturers_id, manufacturers_name, IF(manufacturers_id IN(0,), 'Y', 'N') as flag FROM manufacturers WHERE manufacturers_id IN (0,) ORDER BY manufacturers_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\zencart\includes\classes\db\mysql\query_factory.php on line 101

and:

[02-Mar-2012 15:20:10] PHP Fatal error:  1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p.products_id' at line 1 :: select distinct p.products_id FROM products p LEFT JOIN manufacturers m USING(manufacturers_id) LEFT JOIN products_description pd on p.products_id = pd.products_id JOIN products_to_categories p2c on p.products_id = p2c.products_id JOIN categories c on p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id LEFT JOIN meta_tags_products_description mtpd ON mtpd.products_id= p2c.products_id AND mtpd.language_id = 1 LEFT JOIN tax_rates tr                  ON p.products_tax_class_id = tr.tax_class_id                  LEFT JOIN zones_to_geo_zones gz                  ON tr.tax_zone_id = gz.geo_zone_id                  AND (gz.zone_country_id IS null OR gz.zone_country_id = 0 OR gz.zone_country_id = 222)                  AND (gz.zone_id IS null OR gz.zone_id = 0 OR gz.zone_id = 193) WHERE (p.products_status = 1                AND pd.language_id = 1  AND p2c.products_id = p.products_id                     AND p2c.products_id = pd.products_id                     AND (p2c.categories_id = 5)) AND p.products_date_added >= '20100101' and p.products_date_added <= '20120101' AND (p.products_price_sorter * IF(gz.geo_zone_id IS null, 1, 1 + (tr.tax_rate / 100)) >= 5) AND (p.products_price_sorter * IF(gz.geo_zone_id IS null, 1, 1 + (tr.tax_rate / 100)) <= 55) group by p.products_id, tr.tax_priority GROUP BY p.products_id  in C:\xampp\htdocs\zencart\includes\classes\db\mysql\query_factory.php on line 101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two GROUP BY clauses in your second query, but you can have only one.